# Чтение из файла в переменную

Tags: c#

Есть файл с таким содержимым:

> Tr_RouteFile (    RouteID ( USA1 )    Name ( "Northeast Corridor" )

и такой код:

```
string[] dirroutes = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\games\\train simulator\\routes").GetFiles("*.trk",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();
foreach (string s in dirroutes)
{
    metroComboBox1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

нужно, чтобы `Name("Northeast Corridor")` из файла добавлялся в `metroComboBox1`, как это сделать?

Comment: Вам придётся _распарсить_ строку, содержащуюся в файле. Для этого вы должны для начала придумать _грамматику_ (то есть, описать, что в этом самом файле может быть, а что не может).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отрежьте ненужное.

```
string[] dirroutes = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\games\\train simulator\\routes").GetFiles("*.trk", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();
foreach (string s in dirroutes)
{
  metroComboBox1.Items.Add(s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf("Name")));
}
```

если имеется в виду не название файла и в файле находится ТОЛЬКО тот текст, что описан в топик старте.

```
string[] dirroutes = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\games\\train simulator\\routes").GetFiles("*.trk", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();
foreach (string s in dirroutes)
{
  string line=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(s);
  metroComboBox1.Items.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("Name") + 8, line.LastIndexOf(" )") - line.IndexOf("Name") - 9));
}
```

так-же в обоих условиях, прежде чем парсить строки, хорошо бы добавить условие if(line.IndexOf("Name")>0)

Comment: я правильно понял, что вы хотите Name("Northeast Corridor") ? Или только то, что в кавычках

Comment: s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Name")+8, s.LastIndexOf(" )") - s.IndexOf("Name")-9) :D ну можно по красивее сделать)

Comment: ComboBox1.Items.Add(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Name")+8, s.LastIndexOf(" )") - s.IndexOf("Name")-9)); выдает ошибку что я делаю нетак?

Comment: хм. Так это мы из названия файла пытаемся взять, вы имели в виду содержимое файла? Тогда я буду дополнять ответ. Следует прочитать внутренность File.ReadAllText(S) и эту строку уже парсить описанным выше способом

Comment: дополнил ответ. Просто непонятно, тогда зачем вы  вообще название файла пытались запихать в комбобокс, если вам нужны внутренности? Тем более лучше было взять файлы директории и бежать по ним, а не делать массив строк...

Answer (score 0):

Ну если name всегда заключается в ковычки, то и дайте программе понять, что из полученной строки нужно взять текст только между ковычками. хотя проще удалить все от начала до первой кавычки и от второй до конца.

Comment: как это в коде реализовать?